# Why can't I access Opener's ADO Recordset in IE10?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, internet-explorer-10

This javascript works fine in IE8. It is a child pop-up page trying to move the cursor of an ado recordset to the last entry.

```
opener.listgridid1.recordset.movelast();
```

But the same code gives the following error in IE10 on windows 8.

```
SCRIPT65535: Catastrophic Failure
```

If just the parent page calls the recordset it works fine, and also trying to call other functions on the recordset from the pop-up results in the same error, so I am guessing there is some problem with accessing the recordset from a child page, but i don't know why.

Also, this is being used on a classic asp page, but I don't think that should matter.
Thanks

Comment: Does the compatibility button make any difference

Comment: @John I hadn't thought of that but I just tried and there is no difference. Still the same error. Do you think this points towards something in windows 8?

Comment: Does it work in Firefox or Chrome?  If you know it worked in IE8 you could also try the emulate IE8 meta tag - <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" />

Comment: Could you post your database connection string.  See this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243349